# DWord operations in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

I'm looking for ways of converting an array of byte values in DWord using Ruby.

For example:
[255,1,255,2] -> 11111111 00000001 11111111 000000010

And then I need a way to work with any Byte(or Word) from this DWord and perform bit-wise operations.

Can anyone suggest a method for converting 4 byte array to DWord and then accessing Bytes in resulting DWord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encapsulate your logic in classes. Here is a stripped-down example (would need to add boundary- and error-checking).

```
class Byte
  attr_accessor :value

  def initialize(integer)
    @value = integer
  end

  def to_s
    value.to_s(2).rjust(8,"0")
  end
end

class DWord
  attr_accessor :bytes

  def initialize(*byte_list)
    @bytes = []
    byte_list.each do |b|
      @bytes << Byte.new(b)
    end
  end

  def to_s
    @bytes.map(&:to_s).join(' ')
  end
end
```

You could do something similar for Word, QWord, etc. The above will allow you to do this:

```
dword = DWord.new(255,1,255,2)

puts dword

# 11111111 00000001 11111111 00000010

dword.bytes.each do |b|
  puts "#{b.value} = #{b}"
end

# 255 = 11111111
# 1 = 00000001
# 255 = 11111111
# 2 = 00000010
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> > "101".to_i(2)
> >     => 5

and

> > 5.to_s(2)
> >     => "101"

to convert to other bases pretty easily (the base is the argument)

See
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000802

For bit operations on your numbers,

See
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

And check the chapter **Ruby Bitwise Operators**

Answer (score 0):

First to convert the array of into into a nice string you can do that:

```
puts [255,1,255,2].map{|val| val.to_s(2).rjust(8, '0')}.join(' ')
```

For the binary operations it's pretty simple. It uses the C based operators:

```
OR => 1 | 2 = 3
AND => 1 & 2 = 0
XOR => 1 ^ 3 = 2
```

You should not be using strings for [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)...